# What should I ignore in a C# project when I am using git?

Tags: c#, git

I am new in C# and i am actually working om a project C# using a webService and an edmx database object. I would like to put this project on git but I don't know separate generated files and sources files. Does someone can tell me which kind of files should I ignore in git ?

Thanks,

Comment: https://github.com/github/gitignore

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GitHub has a repository with pre-defined [`.gitignore` files](https://github.com/github/gitignore). The one for C# (i.e. Visual Studio, see [this file](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore)) should be a good starting point:

https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore

Comment: You can also use [www.gitignore.io](http://www.gitignore.io) . Just type in the tags for C# and Visual Studio, and it'll fetch those .gitignore files from github and merge them for you.

Comment: There is no `C#` tag there.

Comment: My bad - just Visual Studio then.